# mouseover wont change string when outside bounds

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Having a problem with creating a mouseover. In my app, I have 3 small images and when the mouse is within the bounds of the image, a string will draw the name of that image. The problem is that when the mouse moves outside of the image, the drawn string still remains and only changes if I move the mouse over another image. So I thought adding an `else` statement would be the logical thing to do. So with the else statement which should change `appName_` into `" "`, the last image `systemButton_[2]` works as desired, but the other two wont draw a string to the screen at all.

So in short:

1. With `else` commented out, each of the images will trigger to draw the appropriate name for the current image the mouse moves over, but will not redraw the string as `" "` when the mouse moves outside of the image.
2. With `else` un-commented, the last image works properly drawing the string and returning the string to `" "` when the mouse is outside the image, but the others cease to work completely.

   ```
       @Override
       public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) 
       {
           super.mouseMoved(event);
           Point mousePosition = event.getPoint();

           for (int i = 0; i < systemButton_.length; i++)
           {   
               if (systemButton_[i].getButtonDimesion().contains(mousePosition))
               {
                   switch (i)
                   {
                   case 0 :
                       appName_ = systemButton_[0].getName();
                       break;
                   case 1 :
                       appName_ = systemButton_[1].getName();
                       break;
                   case 2 :
                       appName_ = systemButton_[2].getName();
                       break;
                   }   
               }
               else 
                   appName_ = " ";
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Where is the appName_ variable displayed? Do you need to call `repaint()` after changing it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels appName_ is used in a drawString

Comment: Then call `repaint()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Call `repaint()` after changing appName_

e.g.,

```
    appName_ = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < systemButton_.length; i++)
    {   
        if (systemButton_[i].getButtonDimesion().contains(mousePosition))
        {
            appName_ = systemButton_[i];  
        }
    }
    repaint();
```